# SQLAlchemy: Two relationship to one table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I have a model where relationships have problems with mapping. My_prosal has data with bad developer_id. I check the query and this problem relates to mapping.

```
class Asset(AbstractBaseModel):
   __tablename__ = "assets"

   project_id = Column(
       ForeignKey("projects.id"),
       type_=UUID(),
       doc="The Project this asset belongs to",
       primary_key=True
   )

...
   project = relationship(
       "Project",
       back_populates="assets",
       lazy='joined',
       overlaps="assets_with_contracts"
   )

   proposals = relationship(
       "Proposal",
       lazy='selectin',
       back_populates='asset',
       viewonly=True
   )


   my_proposal = relationship("Proposal", uselist=False, lazy="noload", viewonly=True)
   user_asset_not_interesting = relationship("UserAssetNotInteresting", uselist=False, lazy="noload", viewonly=True)
   user_asset_viewed = relationship("UserAssetViewed", uselist=False, lazy="noload", viewonly=True)

   __mapper_args__ = {
       "polymorphic_identity": "asset",
   }
```

myproposal loaded from subquery in repository (Repository_pattern):

```
 async def get_assets(self, query_params_filter: Filter = None, additional_filter_params=None, joins=None,
                         initial_query=None):
        current_user = additional_filter_params.get("current_user")

        query = initial_query

        if query is None:
            query = select(self.model)

        if (current_user and current_user.user_type == UserTypes.DEVELOPER and
                "tender_status" in additional_filter_params and additional_filter_params[
                    "tender_status"] != TenderStatuses.ACTIVE):
            subquery_my_proposal = (
                select(Proposal)
                .where(
                    and_(
                        Proposal.developer_id == current_user.id,
                        Proposal.status.in_([ProposalStatuses.APPROVED, ProposalStatuses.PENDING]),
                    )
                )
                .order_by(Proposal.created_at.desc())
                .options(lazyload('*'))
                .limit(1)
                .subquery()
            )

            query = (
                query.add_columns(subquery_my_proposal)
                .outerjoin(subquery_my_proposal, and_(
                    self.model.id == subquery_my_proposal.c.asset_id,
                ))
                .options(joinedload(self.model.my_proposal))
            )
...
```

How do i resolve this conflict? :D Thanks :)

Comment: one of your relationships backpopulates `assets` and the other backpopulates `asset` - is this a typo?